# Raspberry Pi - Pi4J Memory full

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Hi I am new to Raspberry pi. I am using Raspberry pi 3 B and Ubuntu Mate on it and 32gb samsung class 10 memory card. I am using Pi4J to read serial data from connected usbtors232 port on raspberry and on reception of data i am storing all data to different files (each size is 1kb) after some time it started showing memory full df command shows memory full on /dev/root 100% but df -i shows only 10% used. After this i am not able to create any file or folder. Even if after deleting created files. Please help. 
I have tried multiple solutions on stackoverflow. On more point on restart it won't free up space

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not 100% sure, what an inode is (the thing in the `-i` option), but it seems to be just some data, which holds important things about a certain file, such  its owner, permissions, timestamps, and location on the disk.

> An inode is a data structure on a filesystem on Linux and other Unix-like operating systems that stores all the information about a file except its name and its actual data. ([The Linux Information Project](http://www.linfo.org/inode.html))

However, after reading the inode-definition, it seemed, the inode should be smaller than the actual file in normal cases (in the system, there are a lot of very small files).

So I ran `df -h` and `df -h` to compare (`-h` means human readable; represent in MB or KB) See the picture (the last command is explained a little further down):

[image: result of "df -h", "df -ih" and "du -sh /"]

If you compare used and Iused, there's a big diffrence (8.9GB and 180KB).
Also I ran `du -sh /`, which returns the disk usage of a file or directory (`-s` means just the sum in this directory, do not list all subdirectories, `-h` means humanreadable, the slash at the end of the command says, `du` should collect the size of the / (root) directory).

`du` says 9.5 GB, which is a little big larger than the sum of all Used size returned by `df -h`. (I think the reason, why it isn't equals 8.7 GB is, because I've mounted an USB stick, which was calculated too, because you can access it via the root ( / ) filesystem)

After all it seems, you really ran out of space, I'm sorry! But `du` helped me a lot to empty my SD-card form large trash. Just type `du -sh .` and you will see, in which directories the most massive files are.